# Php full compatible sef link - htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

what i'm trying to accomplish is to make my urls compatible with all kinds of extra arguments.

it must be able to work with n number of slashes.so my htaccess gets everything after 127.0.0.1/store/ and sends it redirect.php as id.

```
as in
http://127.0.0.1/store/category/cars/show/1/page/2
or
http://127.0.0.1/store/category/cars/color/red/price/min/100

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/store$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

in my redirect.php i explode slashes to get the script name and its parameters

```
if($_GET['id']){
   $param = explode('/', $_GET['id']);
   $template = $param[0];
   // header redirect -> go to category.php
}
```

this gives me

```
Array
(
    [0] => category
    [1] => electronics-computers
    [2] => show
    [3] => 1
    [4] => page
    [5] => 2
)
```

so far so good, then i try to redirect to the file which is category.php in this example with parameters but since the htaccess controls the traffic, it becomes infinite redirection

i thought i should add some exception to htaccess to not to interfere requests coming from redirect.php but i couldnt make it work

ps: if there is a better way of doing this please let me know

Answer (score 0):

> then i try to redirect to the file which is category.php in this example

Well, that's the thing, you shouldn't be *redirecting* that this stage. Redirecting involves sending a redirect response back to the client and the client then makes a second/new request back to the server (which results in your redirect loop).

> if there is a better way of doing this please let me know

You need to *route* the request. Since you know that the required file is `contact.php` (in this example), then read this file server-side, passing all the necessary parameters and send this in the same response back to the client.